# Are there any pre-print services that accept manuscripts already accepted by a journal?

Tags: preprint, bioinformatics

My publication was accepted by a journal, however I want to post it online prior to publication.

BioRxiv was the original repository of choice, however they do not accept articles accepted by other journals.

**Question:**  Are there archives that accept pre-prints that've already been accepted by a journal?

Comment: Just to check, are you sure that the journal that's accepted your manuscript is cool with you putting it up on a pre-print service?

Answer (score 4):

arXiv has no such restrictions as far as I know.  If your copyright agreement with the journal allows you to post the article on preprint servers, then arXiv will happily accept it before or after acceptance / publication.

When posting to arXiv, you'll need to choose a [license](https://arxiv.org/help/license) that's compatible with your agreement with the journal.

Comment: On the submission page "*Author Approvals Please indicate that all authors have seen and approved the manuscript, and that it hasn't been accepted or published elsewhere."

Comment: @Nakx: Which submission page is that? I just went through a dummy submission on arXiv and I didn't see that text at any point.

Comment: My mistake, I was talking about biorxiv I got confused.